# Здраствуйте! Использую Owl-carousel 2, но она вылазит за блок

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css3, owl-carousel

```
          <div class="technologies"><!-- Блок родитель -->
          <div class="white-block"></div>
          <div class="tech-icon"></div>
          <div class="slider-name">
            <h2>технологии</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="owl-carousel technologies-carousel"><!-- Сама карусель -->
            <div class="tech-item">lalala</div>
            <div class="tech-item">lalala</div>
            <div class="tech-item">lalala</div>
            <div class="tech-item">lalala</div>
            <div class="tech-item">lalala</div>
            <div class="tech-item">lalala</div>
            <div class="tech-item">lalala</div>
            <div class="tech-item">lalala</div>
            <div class="tech-item">lalala</div>
            <div class="tech-item">lalala</div>
            <div class="tech-item">lalala</div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Ближе к вопросу. Есть owl-carousel 2, есть родительский блок в который я хочу ее поместить. В ней должно быть 4 блока в десктопе, ну и при адаптиве по возможности. Но она свободно вылазит за блок, делает его шире ( ширина блока задана в %, может в этом суть) но это меню, и оно должно быть в 50% екрана. Вот еще пара изображений.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А еще скрипт этой карусельки

```
$('.technologies-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:30,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:4
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: ну видимо у вас сайт  'маленький' а экран по больше, поменяйте в параметрах и поставьте значение items:3   для размера  1000px

Comment: Сайт как раз таки щас для больших, и мне нужно чтобы при таком размере было 4 блока :((

Comment: пробовал сделать сами блоки поменьше, выходит вообще чудо(

Answer (score 1):

Могу ошибаться, но карусель подчиняется родительскому блоку. Поэтому лучше обернуть её в div и задать div'у ширину, необходимую вам

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="owl-carousel technologies-carousel"><!-- Сама карусель -->
    <div class="tech-item">lalala</div>
    <div class="tech-item">lalala</div>
    <div class="tech-item">lalala</div>
    <div class="tech-item">lalala</div>
    <div class="tech-item">lalala</div>
    <div class="tech-item">lalala</div>
    <div class="tech-item">lalala</div>
    <div class="tech-item">lalala</div>
    <div class="tech-item">lalala</div>
    <div class="tech-item">lalala</div>
    <div class="tech-item">lalala</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Возможно это решит проблему

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте, решение может быть в

```
.owl-carousel .technologies-carousel {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Если стили будут перебиваться стилями слайдера, добавте !important.

Comment: не работает, даже с !important, и оно быпросто обрезало, и спрятало обрезанную часть, а мне надо чтобы сама каруселька сузилась под размер блока-родителя, и блоковы было 4, может посоветуете какую нибуть еще адаптивную карусель.